# Specify copyright and author in Django translation (.po) file

Tags: python, django, internationalization, translation

When I produce .po files from Django using the `django-admin.py makemessages` command, I end up with header text as follows:

```
# Copyright (C) YEAR THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
```

How should this placeholder be overridden with real values in the code?

Comment: If you change it once, doesn't it keeps the new values after you re-makemessages?

Comment: Excellent - I hadn't even realised it was doing a merge!  Thanks @J.C.Leitão.  I would prefer it to come from django settings though as it appears elsewhere in the code.  If you add this as an answer I'll upvote you though :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The django translations normally does a merging on makemessages. So, if you change the header, it will keep the header you added.

This behavior is consistent, e.g. if you change a string on your code, the .po will keep the translation of the original string, so that nothing is lost in makemessage.